# How to display label message for a particular column in Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

This is my small piece of .aspx code under grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="60px" DataField="Product_Quantity" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity")%>' />
<asp:Button ID ="Button12" runat="server" OnClick="Quantity_Update_Click" CommandArgument="Button12" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers only" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>      
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is my small piece of C# code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["UsernameAdmin"] != null && Session["PasswordAdmin"] != null && Session["BranchAdmin"] != null)
            {
                string username = Session["UsernameAdmin"].ToString();
                string password = Session["PasswordAdmin"].ToString();
                string branch = Session["BranchAdmin"].ToString();
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AdminValidation", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministratorUsername", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministratorPassword", password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchName", branch);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                read.Read();
                if (read.HasRows == false)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx");
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx");
            }

            Label1.Text = Session["BranchAdmin"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = Session["UsernameAdmin"].ToString();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DisplayProducts();
            }

        }

 protected void Quantity_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
            int index = gvr.RowIndex;
            TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox4");
            int Quantity;
            bool qty = int.TryParse(box4.Text, out Quantity);

            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            string ProductNo = row.Cells[0].Text;

            if (Quantity > 0)
            {
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateProductQuantity", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", Quantity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNo", ProductNo);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox("Quantity has been updated");
                DisplayProducts();
            }

            else if (Quantity == 0 || qty == false)
            {
                Label6.Text = "Please add at least one quantity";
                DisplayProducts();
            }

        }
```

Now the problem is under Label6, it is displaying a red line and mentions that:

```
The name 'Label6' does not exist in the current context.
```

But I have added Label6 already in my .aspx code.
I'm not sure where is the mistake I'm making.

Would be helpful, if the recommended syntax solution is provided.

Comment: I think you have to find the Label6 in the context of the datagrid because it's in the itemtemplate.

Comment: Could you post the entire gridview markup ?

Comment: I have added the gridview markup ... you can refer back to the edited .aspx code again :)

Comment: Ok, and what does DisplayProducts do ?

Comment: DisplayProducts is a private method that displays the product lists (from database table) in grid view format

Comment: So if you enter 0 in Quantity, you basically reload the dataset, because you call it in the if (Quantity > 0)'s else statement

Comment: Exactly ... You are correct ... But I want that Label6 message to be displayed in the gridview  .. if I enter 0 in quantity text box

Comment: I guess you could put a second validator to check if the value is greater then zero. And the check if the validators are true before doing your update code ?

Comment: Something like this ?


<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Must be &gt; 0"
      Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer"
      ValueToCompare="0" />

Comment: Yes after using CompareValidator ... it is working now :) ... One last thing .... You showed CompareValidator with Integer Number ... It would be helpful if you can show me CompareValidator with Decimal Number :)

Comment: I guess you could use a regex validator for that.
Please upvote the answer if you find it helpfull :)

Comment: Is this how you use for decimal ? ... <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0.00" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Decimal" ValueToCompare="0.00" />

Comment: Looks about right :) Havent tried it :)

Comment: Actually this one works when dealing with decimal ... <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0.00" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Currency" ValueToCompare="0.00" />

Answer (score 1):

Just like you find a Textbox controll within the grid by the rowindex, you also have to find the label.

Please try this code.
Of course, i'm unable to test the sql connection.

```
    protected void Quantity_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        int index = gvr.RowIndex;
        TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("TextBox4");
        Label Label6 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("Label6");
        int Quantity;
        bool qty = int.TryParse(box4.Text, out Quantity);

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        string ProductNo = row.Cells[0].Text;

        if (Quantity > 0)
        {
            string CS;
            CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateProductQuantity", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", Quantity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNo", ProductNo);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox("Quantity has been updated");
            DisplayProducts();
        }

        else if (Quantity == 0 || qty == false)
        {
            Label6.Text = "Please add at least one quantity";
            DisplayProducts();
        }

    }
```

Please note that i changed the GridView1.Rows[index] to not include the .Cells[] part, since findcontrol will look in the entire row for controlls

Comment: I have used your recommended logic ... Now during compilation there is no error in C# code .... Now if I add any random number inside the quantity box and click update button, it gets updated and displays message box "Quantity has been updated"... But there is one issue ... If I enter the value 0 in the quantity box and then click update button, the value gets redirected to back to its previous non-zero value but it does not display the label message ... You may refer back to <asp:Button> and <asp:Label> in my .aspx code and see if I made mistake over there or not.

Comment: did you use if (!Page.IsPostBack) in your page load ?

Please show me your Page_Load event code

Comment: Now you can check my Page_Load event code in my post. I have edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should take care of your needs (this assumes that all of your cells contain integers):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            // Set the capacity label text
            Label1.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;


            // Calc the sum of all of the row values
            int sum = 0;
            foreach(TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                  sum+= Int32.Parse(c.Text);
            }


            // Set the sum label text value
            Label2.Text = sum.ToString();        }
    }
```

Tweak the code as you may need